# `[ ]` operator leads to compile error on map

Tags: c++, c++11, stdmap

I am trying to get an element from a map in a for loop. Following the example on [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at) I try this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    map<int, int> mapping;

    mapping.insert(pair<int, int>(11,1));
    mapping.insert(pair<int, int>(12,2));
    mapping.insert(pair<int, int>(13,3));

    for (const auto &it : mapping)
        mapping[it]++;


    cout << "array: ";
    for (const auto &it : mapping)
        cout << it.second << " ";

    return 0;
}
```

Which gives the following compilation error with gcc:

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:15:16: error: no match for 'operator[]' (operand types are 'std::map<int, int>' and 'const std::pair<const int, int>')
         mapping[it]++;
```

If I understand it correctly the problem is that the `auto` is resolved to a `std::pair<const int, int>` for which no `[]` operator is defined. I was wondering whether there is a way to get this to work.

See for the full compilation error [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/36835883c9eed997)

Comment: Unlike languages with similar syntax to C++, it is not the key. Instead `it` is the actual pair in the map.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about just

```
for (auto &it : mapping)
    ++it.second;
```

for your first loop?